# Unexpected error in testing and learning about graphs in C

Tags: c, directed-graph, adjacency-list, undirected-graph

I have recently started to study this particular book for algorithms and data structure [SkienaTheAlgorithmDesignManual.pdf](http://mimoza.marmara.edu.tr/~msakalli/cse706_12/SkienaTheAlgorithmDesignManual.pdf), from which I've heard a lot of praise not only on the Internet,but from my Algorithms Design teacher as well at college,and I ended up having some errors with some code used from the book on page 153(on the book itself) or 165(pdf format).

Here's the code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdbool.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#define MAXV 1000
typedef struct  {
    int y;
    int weight;
    struct edgenode *next;
}edgenode;
typedef struct {
    edgenode *edges[MAXV + 1];
    int degree[MAXV + 1];
    int nvertices;
    int nedges;
    bool directed;
}graph;

void initialize_graph(graph *g, bool directed);
void read_graph(graph *g, bool directed);
void insert_edge(graph *g, int x, int y, bool directed);
void print_graph(graph *g);
void initialize_graph(graph *g, bool directed) {
    int i;

    g->nvertices = 0;
    g->nedges = 0;
    g->directed = directed;
    for (i = 1; i <= MAXV; i++) {
        g->degree[i] = 0;
        g->edges[i] = NULL;
    }

}

void read_graph(graph *g, bool directed) {
    int i;
    int m;
    int x, y;
    initialize_graph(g, directed);
    scanf("%d %d", &(g->nvertices), &m);
    for (i = 1; i <= m; i++) {
        scanf("%d %d", &x, &y);
        insert_edge(g, x, y, directed);
    }
}

void insert_edge(graph *g, int x, int y, bool directed) {
    edgenode *p;
    p = malloc(sizeof(edgenode));
    p->weight = NULL;
    p->y = y;
    p->next = g->edges[x];
    g->edges[x] = p;
    g->degree[x]++;
    if (directed == false)
        insert_edge(g, y, x, true);
    else
        g->nedges++;
}

void print_graph(graph *g) {
    int i;
    edgenode *p;
    for (i = 1; i <= g->nvertices; i++) {
        printf("%d ", i);
        p = g->edges[i];
        while (p != NULL) {
            printf(" %d", p->y);
            p = p->next;
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
main() {
    bool directed = true;
    graph *g;
    read_graph(g, directed);
    print_graph(g);
    system("pause");
}
```

Here are the errors:

> > > 1>c:\users\dragos\source\repos\learninggraph\learninggraph\main.c(47): warning C4047: '=': 'int' differs in levels of indirection from 'void *'
> > >       1>c:\users\dragos\source\repos\learninggraph\learninggraph\main.c(49): warning C4133: '=': incompatible types - from 'edgenode *' to 'edgenode *'
> > >       1>c:\users\dragos\source\repos\learninggraph\learninggraph\main.c(65): warning C4133: '=': incompatible types - from 'edgenode *' to 'edgenode *'
> > >       1>c:\users\dragos\source\repos\learninggraph\learninggraph\main.c(73): error C4700: uninitialized local variable 'g' used
> > >       1>Done building project "LearningGraph.vcxproj" -- FAILED.
> > >       ========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========

I think that the main problem is the "incompatible types",but I may be as very well be wrong.

Comment: for `malloc()` and `system()` you have to `#include <stdlib.h>`. Update your code and your post with the remaining errors please

Comment: @user3469811 still doesn't work,but I get less warnings.

Comment: `graph *g;` can be `graph g;` in _main_, see my answer for more

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `insert_edge`

> ```
>  p->weight = NULL;
> ```

is invalid because *weight* is an *int* but *NULL* a pointer (typically `(void*)0`)

In `insert_edge`

> ```
>  p->next = g->edges[x];
> ```

is invalid because *next* is the undefined type `struct edgenode *` but `edges[x]` is `edgenode *`. To solve that you have to replace

```
typedef struct {
    int y;
    int weight;
    struct edgenode *next;
}edgenode;
```

by

```
typedef struct edgenode {
    int y;
    int weight;
    struct edgenode *next;
}edgenode;
```

The reason is the same in `print_graph` line

> ```
>  p = p->next;
> ```

Explicitly set the return type of *main* as *int*

In *main* you call `read_graph` with *g* never set/initialized so when it is dereferenced in `read_graph` the behavior is undefined, and this is also the case in `print_graph`. Just replace

> ```
>  graph *g;
>  read_graph(g, directed);
>  print_graph(g);
> ```

by

```
graph g;
read_graph(&g, directed);
print_graph(&g);
```

---

Full modified version :

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdbool.h>

#define MAXV 1000

typedef struct edgenode {
    int y;
    int weight;
    struct edgenode *next;
}edgenode;

typedef struct {
    edgenode *edges[MAXV + 1];
    int degree[MAXV + 1];
    int nvertices;
    int nedges;
    bool directed;
}graph;

void initialize_graph(graph *g, bool directed);
void read_graph(graph *g, bool directed);
void insert_edge(graph *g, int x, int y, bool directed);
void print_graph(graph *g);
void initialize_graph(graph *g, bool directed) {
    int i;

    g->nvertices = 0;
    g->nedges = 0;
    g->directed = directed;
    for (i = 1; i <= MAXV; i++) {
        g->degree[i] = 0;
        g->edges[i] = NULL;
    }

}

void read_graph(graph *g, bool directed) {
    int i;
    int m;
    int x, y;
    initialize_graph(g, directed);
    scanf("%d %d", &(g->nvertices), &m);
    for (i = 1; i <= m; i++) {
        scanf("%d %d", &x, &y);
        insert_edge(g, x, y, directed);
    }
}

void insert_edge(graph *g, int x, int y, bool directed) {
    edgenode *p;
    p = malloc(sizeof(edgenode));
    p->weight = 0;
    p->y = y;
    p->next = g->edges[x];
    g->edges[x] = p;
    g->degree[x]++;
    if (directed == false)
        insert_edge(g, y, x, true);
    else
        g->nedges++;
}

void print_graph(graph *g) {
    int i;
    edgenode *p;
    for (i = 1; i <= g->nvertices; i++) {
        printf("%d ", i);
        p = g->edges[i];
        while (p != NULL) {
            printf(" %d", p->y);
            p = p->next;
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}

int main() {
    bool directed = true;
    graph g;
    read_graph(&g, directed);
    print_graph(&g);
    system("pause");
}
```

Compilation :

```
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ gcc -pedantic -Wall -Wextra g.c
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $
```

Comment: One more thing.Why do I need to explicitly set the return type of main as int?Isn't it set as int by default by any C compiler?

Comment: @Neri-kun to avoid the warning `Wimplicit-int`

Answer (score 1):

You never allocated any memory for `graph *g`.

There's no need for this to be a pointer, make it a normal variable and pass its address to the functions.

```
int main() {
    bool directed = true;
    graph g;
    read_graph(&g, directed);
    print_graph(&g);
    system("pause");
}
```